# 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: mysql

Me he conectado a mi bastion de Amazon y ahora estoy intentando conectarme a mi base de datos. Sin embargo, cuando intento ejecutar mysql me sale un error:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> mysql --u admin -p password -h127.0.0.1 -P4000
mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mysql --u admin -pfswR6c9Vbq5AvBNd4jntUCzYJaeTP_7F -h127.0.0.1 -P4306
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Por lo tento tengo MySQL por aqui:

```
PS C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL> dir


    Directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        27/04/2021     08:20                MySQL Installer - Community
d-----        25/06/2021     11:33                MySQL Server 5.7
-a----        14/06/2021     10:15           2238 MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE.lnk
```

Por desgracia no hay `bin/` en el mio directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deseas ejecutar el comando `mysql` desde cualquier directorio tenes que agregar a las "Variables de entorno" de Window el path al `exe`

#### Pasos:

1. Clic derecho en el botón Inicio > clic en "Sistema"
2. Clic en "Opciones avanzadas del sistema"
3. Clic en la solapa "Avanzado"
4. Clic en el botón "Variables de entorno"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Seleccionar "Path" en "Variables del usuario" o "Variables del sistema" (*mi preferido*) y clic en el botón "Editar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Agregar el path al directorio donde se encuentra el `exe`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

7. Clic "Aceptar" en la ventana de "Editar variables de entorno"
8. Clic "Aceptar" en la ventana de "Variables de entorno"
9. Clic "Aceptar" en la ventana de "Propiedades del sistema"
10. Abrir una nueva consola/powershell/cmd

**PD:** Disculpen, pero mi Windows esta en ingles xD

---

#### Opción 2:

Desde la consola ejecutar el comando:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\al\directorio\
```

*Nota:* La "desventaja" es que es temporal y solo se aplica a la sesión de la consola.

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos !! Por desgracia no hay bin/ en el mio directorio. Tengo MySQL Server 5.7 y parece que hay vinculos... Piensen que puedo dar el mismo camino y usara estos para empezar mysql en el mio terminal?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica es que lo estas buscando en el directorio equivocado. En tu pregunta estas viendo los accesos directo que se agregan al Menu Inicio. Si miras las propiedades de los "link" va a encontrar el path al `exe`

Comment: Te dejo [un ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJlUW.png) de como buscar el path en los lnk

Comment: Merci Marcos! La tua respuesta es perfecta para estupidos como mi ^^